# maven build succeeds, but eclipse build fails

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have an Eclipse / Maven project: The build with Maven succeeds, but Eclipse does have compile-time errors and cannot build. 
My Eclipse is Neon (4.6.3) and I am using the build-in Maven and JDK 1.8

Could you help me solve the problem?

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>seller</groupId>
  <artifactId>home.digest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>home.digest Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>home.digest</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Eclipse fails to recognize the following imports in a class:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
```

The Eclipse project has the following properties:

[image]

Comment: You have not told us what errors you are seeing.  It's rather difficult to help without that.

Comment: As I said above: Eclipse does have compile-time errors (does not recognize the three imports mentioned above, i.e. Eclipse does not find the classes in the imports section

Comment: First check please try to build on command line...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that the jar file was corrupt:

[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\User.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.11\httpcore-4.4.11.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

I solved the problem by replacing the dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

by the dependency on an earlier version:

4.4.10

Comment: Deleting the file `C:\Users\User.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.11\httpcore-4.4.11.jar`, right-clicking the project and choosing _Maven > Update Project..._ should work too. As far as I know, there was a bug that has been fixed and that often caused corrupted Maven downloads. [Please upgrade](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_upgrade_Eclipse_IDE%3F#Always_enable_major_upgrades). You are five releases behind.

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. I will keep it in mind for the next time. Actually the very weird thing in this case was that Maven build succeeded, despite of the error message. How is it possible?!

Comment: I have no idea why the Maven build succeeds. If you run Maven on the command line and not from inside of Eclipse, it might be that different local Maven repositories are used.

Answer (score 0):

Hello

First of all, You should check to contain the apache jar file your maven local folder. Some version folder have in your local maven folder. But doesn't have jar file.

OR

this line code add to your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hello, apache jar files are already in the local repository. And, yes, I do have the above dependency in my pom.xml file (see above)

Comment: @AlexMi <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.10</version>
</dependency>  did you use it?